# Node.js and PHP sites on same server

Tags: linux, php, website, node.js

I have a node.js site running on port 8080 of my Linux server. I also have, on the same sarver, a PHP site (bugzilla) running on port 80.
So my current configuration is:

- http://example.com:8080 (node.js application)
- http://example.com/bugzilla (bugzilla site)

I want to have both sites running on port 80 like this:

- http://example.com/mynodejs (node.js application)
- http://example.com/bugzilla (bugzilla site)

Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need a `reverse proxy` to manage the requests.

Comment: Have you tried to google it? It's a pretty common problem and I'm sure that there's a lot of articles out there on the web.

Comment: @gronostaj: Yes I tried Googling but perhaps I was using the wrong keywords as I couldn't find anything. I'll try now searching `reverse proxy` thanks to @kinnectus